# Run time complexity of nearest neighbor

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour, time-complexity

A paper titled, "***Efficient Neighbor Searching in Nonlinear Time Series Analysis (1996)***" [download link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.35.2471) mentions that the time complexity for the naive NN approach is $N^2/2$ i.e., $O(N^2/2)$ where $N$ denotes the number of datapoints. I have attached a screenshot from the paper where this complexity is mentioned (second paragraph). However, in textbooks it is mentioned that the complexity of $O(N)$. I am a bit confused. Can somebody please help, what is the correct answer and why $O(N^2/2)$ is mentioned in the paper.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper mentions that the time complexity for the naive NN approach is $^2/2$ *in order to argue for using non-naive algorithms* that are faster for large $N$.

In fact, the paper goes on to say that $O(N\log N)$ is possible for arbitrary data distributions, using $k$-d trees and their variants and that $O(N)$ is possible for some data distributions.

My impression is that interest now is more in the dependence on dimension rather than on $N$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer....by naive NN do you mean the k nearest neighbor given here: https://sebastianraschka.com/pdf/lecture-notes/stat479fs18/02_knn_notes.pdf  Can you please clarify this point?

Comment: I mean the algorithm where you compute all $N\choose 2$ distances between pairs of   points and pick the smallest ones.